# Null Check throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, null

Sometimes it happens that I have written a code to check NullPointerException like below,

```
if(str!=null)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

and the null check itself throws NUllPointerException.

How to solve it.

Edited:
Actually this code was getting null pointer,

```
Map params = new HashMap();
if(params != null && params.get("requestType"))
{
    //some null safe code goes here
}
```

i understood later that params.get() was throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you post your full code ??

Comment: You don't have code to "check NullPointerException" as you say, but you have code that checks for `null`. It is impossible for this code itself to throw a NullPointerException, so the problem must be somewhere else in your code, in a place that you haven't posted yet to SO.

Comment: that check didn't throw exceptions. perhaps you did if (str!=null); { } or if (str.foobar() != null) { }

Comment: How could one throws NullPointerException when it wont deal with object manipulation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to be saying that:

```
if (str != null) {
    doSomething();
}
```

is throwing a `NullPointerException` in the comparison.

That is **impossible**.  So I expect that what is really happening is one of the following:

- You have misinterpreted the stack trace, and the NPE is not being thrown there.
- The actual code is substantially different to the illustrative example.
- You are not executing the code that you think you are executing.  For example, you might not have recompiled it ... or you may be executing a stale copy of the `.class` or `.jar` file.
- You have managed to seriously confuse your IDE.  (Sometimes you can get very strange behaviour from a confused IDE ...)

---

<sup>The only situations where that code might give an NPE that is not an artefact of something else you are doing wrong is if have a damaged Java (or IDE) installation, or if your hardware is faulty.  I would discount those explanations as basically implausible.</sup>

---

**Update**

Now you say that:

```
Map params = new HashMap();
if(params != null && params.get("requestType"))
{
    //some null safe code goes here
}
```

throws an NPE in `params.get`.  I have to say that this is nonsense.

1. The code won't compile.  The `params.get` call doesn't return something that is `boolean` or that can be automatically converted to a `boolean`.
2. If we ignore the compilation errors, then `params.get` on a thread-confined map can only throw an NPE if `params` is `null`.  This map *is* thread-confined, and the previous check ensures that `params` isn't `null`.

My previous conclusions stand.  This is impossible.

Hint: this *could* be a threading problem.  It is possible to get intermittent NPE's if you update a `HashMap` with one thread and read it with another, and you don't synchronize properly.

Comment: recently i have been working on a support project, that file was jsp file and code written in scriptlet was giving NPE at the condition like above, so asked the question, thnx for reply.

Comment: My conclusion is that the code in the actual project was substantially different to the examples in your question.  I'm afraid we can't give you meaningful answers if you show us the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked it properly? Can you explain me scenario? Is it in java?
If it is in Java then here is a sample code that works fine you cross check.
If it is a local variable also it works fine.

```java
    class string 
    {
        static String str;

        public static void main(String[] args){
           if(str!=null){
               System.out.println("hi");
           }else{
               System.out.println("bye");
           }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.   The question is about whether `str != null` throws an exception.